# auto increment value in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In code:

```
<% @offers.each do |offer|%>
  <%= offer.percentageOff%> <b>% OFF on order of</b>
  <%= image_tag('1407951522',:size=>'10x10',:alt=>'Rs.')%>
  <%= offer.amountforDiscount%>
  <%= button_to 'Delete',{:action=>'destroy',:id=>offer.id},class: "" %>
<% end %>
```

I am new in rails. I want to show all the offers in a *numbered list*, I can't use database table because `id` is not in order. For example:

1. 30 % OFF on order of Rs.2000
2. 13 % OFF on order of Rs.1000

How do i achieve this?

Comment: You're using rails, so maybe HTML can help you. If it's just a matter of rendering an ordered list, have you tried putting your entries in a `<ol></ol>`?

Comment: I showed you how to do it using Ruby method, and you decided to stick to "Java way". But that's your decision :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easiest way if you don't want to use `each_with_index` then You can define variable `@count=0` and display, as loop occur it will be increment by 1

```
<% @count = 0 %>
<% @offers.each do |offer|%> 
<%= @count += 1 %> #I guess you want this to show Sr.No
...... # your code
<% end %>
```

### **[each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index)** way :

```
<% @offers.each_with_index do |offer, index|%> 
 <%= index + 1 %> # index starts from 0, so added 1 to start numbering from 1
  ...... # your code
<% end %>
```

Comment: for me, i need to declare initialize the count with <%= @count = 0 %>

Comment: @V-SHY : yes you have do it as you are putting this code in erb template. but if you just want to intialized then no need to print it. simply `<% @count = 0 %>`

Comment: I guess <%= index += 1 %> will do the incrementation correectly.